# How to create custom url structure for custom post type categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am basically trying to rewrite the url structure for a custom taxonomy in wordpress from:

https://dev.energypages.com/specialization/energy-supply-distribution

To:

https://dev.energypages.com/specialization?specializingin=(parent category slug here)

And:

https://dev.energypages.com/specialization?specializingin=(parent category slug here)&specialitiesin=(Child category slug here)

I have been looking in to query vars but can't seem to figure out the code structure for what i need.

Any help on how to get started would be much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for custom permalinks for the custom post type.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/
I think it will work for you.